# Laravel 8.x, make fake model reationships?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to run a faker factory for relationships, but the field always returns NULL. How do fake a model relationship *without* hitting the database?

I have a Map factory with a one-to-one relationship to a parent Event table. I need to fake this relationship for unit testing:

```php
/**
 * Define the model's default state.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'event' => 'faker.' . join('_', $this->faker->words),
        'category' => $this->faker->word,
        'sub_category' => $this->faker->word,
        'priority' => $this->faker->randomElement(['normal', 'high']),
        'event' => Event::factory()->makeOne(),
    ];
}
```

This returns a fake model, but `event` is null, from the debugger:

```
result = {array} [5]
 event = "faker.eum_voluptatibus_aut"
 category = "libero"
 sub_category = "aut"
 priority = "high"
 event = null
```

I tried using states, but the same thing happens:

```php
public function disabled()
{
    return $this->state([
        'event' => Event::factory()->makeOne(['enabled' => false]),
    ]);
}
```

The object is returned with an empty `event` value. I need a faker object I can transverse down into: `if ($object->event->enabled) [...]`. How do I generate fake model relationships?

Comment: I suspect this question originated from a misunderstanding of how factories work; your array should not have an `event` key as that is the name of a relationship. Rather it should use the name of the database column, i.e. `event_id`, and of course cannot contain random text since it's a numeric column.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel 8.x you must consider using methods used on the docs, it must look like that :

```
/**
 * Define the model's default state.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'event' => 'faker.' . join('_', $this->faker->words),
        'category' => $this->faker->word,
        'sub_category' => $this->faker->word,
        'priority' => $this->faker->randomElement(['normal', 'high']),
        'event_id' => Event::factory(),
    ];
}

/**
 * Indicate that the map is disabled.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory
 */
public function disabled()
{
    return $this->state([
        'event_id' => Event::factory()->create(['enabled' => false]),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found, so far, is to manually set the `event` key myself in my tests. It's not the ideal or elegant solution.

```php
$fieldMap = Map::factory()->makeOne();
$fieldMap->event = Event::factory(['enabled' => false])->makeOne();
```

I don't like this approach. Why can't I define factories within factories?